# How to create class objects from dictionary

Tags: python, loops, class, dictionary

Would like to create class objects out of dictionary

Hi I know this question has been asked in different variations but I'm pretty new to Python hence I really still need some help after browsing existing Q&A. Thanks in advance.

Problem -- I'm using qt designer for a UI. There is a huge set of buttons that I'm trying to define in classes.

I would like to be able to use a dictionary and create a loop, looping through each key to generate class objects and definitions from values of the dictionary.

Right now this is what I'm doing, and I think it's really dumb:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
    .....
    .....

    def change_name_of_button(self):
        self.apple_label.setText('apple_is_big')
        self.orange_label.setText('orange_is_small')

    def press_button(self):
        self.apple_button.clicked.connect(self.eat_apple)
        self.orange_button.clicked.connect(self.eat_orange)

    def eat_apple(self):
        print('nom nom nom')

#........
```

So is there anyway where I could just have a global dictionary that stores all the names/objects under the key "apple" and I could use that to generate everything in class?

I want to have something like this?

```
dict = {
     'Apple': ['apple_label', 'apple_button', 'eat_apple', 'nom nom nom'],
     'Orange': [ .... ],
     ...
}

def xxxx (self):
    for key, value in dict:
        self.dict[key][1].clicked.connect(self......)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It is unclear what are the elements in `['apple_label', 'apple_button', 'eat_apple', 'nom nom nom']`

Comment: @Netwave, hi, so basically in QT designer tool, I could have predefined 'apple_label' as the name of a QT label within the tool. By loading the UI file, the text of 'apple label' can be changed by    '''''self.apple_label.setText('apple_is_big')'''''                                            Similarly, 'apple_button' is a predefined button object in QT designer tool.                  'eat_apple' is just a name that I would like to give a function within the script. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
d = {
     'apple': {'label' : 'apple_label', 'button_result': 'nom nom nom'},
     'orange': { .... },
     ...
}

def initialize(self, d):
    for name, config in d.items():
        getattr(self, f"{name}_label").setText(config["label"])
        def callback():
            print(config["button_result"])
        getattr(self, f"{name}_button").clicked.connect(callback)
```

Notice that I modified the dictionary a bit, you can arrange however you want.